# Concrete mix for outdoor countertop

Tags: concrete

I am building a brick BBQ, and I need to put a surface or "countertop" on which to lay fire bricks.

I have seen this done in many videos. I will create a "shuttered" area, use steel mesh for reinforcement.

But I don't know what concrete mix would be suitable for this. I'd like it to be fairly smooth,but obviously strong.

Here is an example - I am thinking of a much smaller version!

[image]

Comment: For concrete counters that are exposed? I am not sure why you would use fire brick on a countertop, fire brick is not a good counter top surface. I mix for 5000 lb dry strength, I also use add mix modifier and white Portland cement, the aggregate depends on the house white, brown gray or a random mix of colors, once cast you finish with a grinder and polish the surface. There are tutorials start to finish videos online. I would watch a few it would have saved me some learning mistakes when I did my first ones back in the 90’s but there was not so much help available back then.

Comment: Firebricks are needed because it will have the charcoal on top. Colour is not important as it will have the firebricks on top. I just want to know which mix ( or which ready mixed Blue Circle product) is needed.